# How to delete a row in one section of INI file using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to delete a row inside the section of an INI file, but after triggering the delete code, The INI file contents stays the same. The deleted data of the INI File does not appear to be deleted.

CODE:

```
  <DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Public Shared Function WritePrivateProfileSection( _
        ByVal lpAppName As String, _
        ByVal lpString As String, _
        ByVal lpValue As String, _
        ByVal lpFileName As String) As Boolean
    End Function   

    Public Sub DeleteSection(ByRef sApp As String, ByRef sKey As String)
        Try
            Dim ret As Boolean
            Dim sBuff As New System.Text.StringBuilder
            sBuff.Capacity = 256

            ret = WritePrivateProfileSection(sApp, sKey, "", m_sIniFile)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

USAGE:

```
m_ini.DeleteSection("AppName", "AppKey")
```

The main purpose of this is to Delete the key and its value.

But the problem is after deleting it, nothing has changed on the INI File.

Regards,

Comment: Not that it matters for this problem but what are those method parameters declared `ByRef`? There's no good reason for that to be the case. `ByVal` is the default for a reason.

Comment: Ok Sir. I will change it. But the main problem is still not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

As pointed out by Jimi in the comments, `WritePrivateProfileString` can delete a key. It appears that you should indeed be calling `WritePrivateProfileString` rather than `WritePrivateProfileSection` and the third argument should be `Nothing` rather than an empty `String`.

Also, while the actual names don't matter when executing, it's a good idea to be consistent in your code to avoid confusion. As such, the parameters, in order, should be `lpAppName`, `lpKeyName`, `lpString` and `lpFileName`. If you want to use .NET-style naming instead, use `appName`, `keyName`, `[string]` and `fileName`. You might use `value` instead of `[string]` to avoid the need to escape a keyword.

ORIGINAL:

I've never used either so I'm not completely confident in this answer but, from what I can see, you are mangling `WritePrivateProfileSection` and `WritePrivateProfileString` into a combination that doesn't do either. Your function is named `WritePrivateProfileSection` but that function has three parameters, not four. It is `WritePrivateProfileString` that has four but that doesn't do what you want.

`WritePrivateProfileString` will write a value to a key, which is fine if you want to clear that key but if you want to delete it, it's not right. `WritePrivateProfileSection` takes a single `String` containing all the keys and values to write to a section so that's what you need to use and you need to omit the key you want deleted from that `String`.

It appears that what you actually need to do is read all the keys and values in that section and then construct a `String` from them, leaving out the key you want to delete. You then call `WritePrivateProfileSection` with that `String` to overwrite the section with the modified data. The `GetPrivateProfileSection` function will get a `String` containing all the current keys and values, so you should call that, process the result and then pass the manipulated data to `WritePrivateProfileSection`.

Comment: If what the OP actually wants is to delete one of the Keys in a section (as it appears), there's `WritePrivateProfileString` for that, passing `null` as the `lpValue` argument. The same applies to `WritePrivateProfileSection`, which can delete an entire section, passing the name of an existing Section and `null` as the `lpString` argument.

Answer (score 0):

I also recommend using WritePrivateProfileString, but you should declare it correct.

```
' Writes String values
<DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode,
           SetLastError:=True, EntryPoint:="WritePrivateProfileStringW")>
Public Shared Function WritePrivateProfileString(
    Section As String,
    Key As String,
    WriteStr As String,
    IniFile As String) As Integer
End Function
```

In .NET the standard is Unicode, so use the EntryPoint with the W ending (= wide)

Then deleting of a Key/Entry is easy:

```
Public Sub DeleteEntry(IniFile As String, Section As String, Key As String)
    WritePrivateProfileString(Section, Key, vbNullString, IniFile)
End Sub
```

You could also delete a complete section with WritePrivateProfileString:

```
Public Sub DeleteSection(IniFile As String, Section As String)
    WritePrivateProfileString(Section, vbNullString, vbNullString, IniFile)
End Sub
```

Comment: How about sir, Inside the section, I want to delete only one key and the value of that ? Is that possible?

Comment: Sure. Then use the DeleteEntry function in the middle of my three code sections. This is the function for this task. Or, if you want to use only the WritePrivateProfileString function, insert the key name at the second parameter.